# Blazor logs - how to add time?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have my Blazor app run on Ubuntu server. It works, it even write logs (its console output is redirected to a log file), however - there is no time in logs. Is there a way to enable event times? Is there a way to have errors and other types of messages in separate files? Is there a way to add a proper logger that would replace that built in one writing to the console?

I need a logger to log unhandled exceptions with the time they occured. Now I see those exceptions in the redirected console output, but I don't have information about the time.

Comment: Try serilog or any of other third party logging libraries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#third-party-logging-providers

Comment: Thanks for recommending Serilog, I like it. It works like charm.